# Logstash save JSON field into date type directly

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I've a JSON input as

```
{"name":"peter", "time1": "2014-12-23 13:45:23"}
{"name":"tom", "time1": "2014-11-30 04:55:34"}
```

And filter

```
json {
    source => "message"
}

date {
    locale => "en"
    match => ["time1", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => "time2"
}
```

Currently I was able to parse the `time1` and get `time2` as **Date** field in elastic search. However, in the elastic search, the field `time1` is still **String**.

Is it possible to alter the type of `time1` as `**Date**` directly without creating a `time2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
date {
    locale => "en"
    match => ["time1", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => "time1"
}
```